# How to skip double quotes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, powershell

I have following command:

```
    exec 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command  & "{[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin", "Machine");$env:JAVA_HOME}"'
```

It's not working because the external double quote is getting closed by another double quote. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with Ruby. Your Ruby string is in single quotes, which do not require escaping double quotes. You don't have to escape double quotes because of Ruby.

Comment: `exec 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command  "& {[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(\"JAVA_HOME\", \"C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\", \"Machine\");$env:JAVA_HOME}"'`

Comment: @PetSerAl No. That does not change anything.

Comment: Could you post the command you're trying to execute, i.e. without `exec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you want a string fragment that would be interpreted as an escaped double quote, then you need to escape the escape character: `\\"`.</strike>

Comment: [That](http://ideone.com/hWQKEA) says, that `\\"` and `\"` produce exactly same result.

Comment: Actually, I think this is wrong. (Not sure why it was accepted.) The escape character in PowerShell is backtick, not backslash. The backslash is used as a path fragment separator in DOS, Windows, and PowerShell, and thus using it as an escape character would be extremely cumbersome.

Comment: Unfortunately, I deleted my Windows-VM, so I cannot test it myself. (Note to self: check out whether there are free Azure accounts I could get.)

Comment: exec 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command  " & {[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(\\"JAVA_HOME\\", \\"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\\");$env:JAVA_HOME}"'
This worked for me.

Comment: @Manish Does it not work if you use single backslash, as in my comment to your question?